# cakephp Ajax: city select box not populating when state is selected

Tags: ajax, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate the city select box based on the selected state (which is also a select box) using Ajax. When i select state, the city select box is not being populated.

There are 5 models below: Student, MerryParent, MerryClass, State, City. All of them are related to one another.

Can someone please tell me on what am I doing wrong? thank you.

The following are the models:
student.php

```
 <?php
 class Student extends appModel{
var $name='Student';
var $belongsTo=array('MerryParent','State','City','MerryClass');

          }
      ?>
```

merry_parent.php

```
     <?php
     class MerryParent extends appModel{
var $name='MerryParent';
$hasMany=array(
        'Student'=>array(
        'className'=>'Student',
        'foreignKey'=>'merry_parent_id'
                )
            );
$belongsTo=array('State','City','MerryClass');

                     ?>
```

merry_class.php

```
         <?php
            class MerryClass extends AppModel{
         var $name='MerryClass';
         var $hasMany=array
    ('Student'=>array(
            'className'=>'Student',
            'foreignKey'=>'class_id'
            ),
     'MerryParent'
    );
        var $belongsTo=array('State','City');
        //var $displayField='class_name';
           }
          ?>
```

city.php

```
      <?php
        class City extends AppModel{
    var $name='City';
    var $belongsTo='State';
    var $hasMany=array('MerryParent','MerryClass',
            'Student'=>array(
                'className'=>'Student',
                'foreignKey'=>'city_id'
                )
            );
                 }
        ?>
```

state.php

```
               <?php
                      class State extends AppModel{
                         var $name='State';
                         var $hasMany=array(
            'MerryParent',
            'MerryClass',
            'City'=>array(
            'className'=>'City',
            'foreignKey'=>'state_id'
            //'dependent'=>true
            ),
            'Student'=>array(
            'className'=>'Student',
            'foreignKey'=>'state_id'
            )
        );

              }
             ?>
```

The controllers
students_controller.php

```
<?php
class StudentsController extends AppController{
 var $name='Students';
 var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript');
 var $components=array('RequestHandler');

function getcities(){

    $options=$this->Student->City->find('list',
                                    array
                                    ('conditions'=>array(
                                                    'City.state_id'=>$this->data['Student']['state_id']
                                                    ),
                                     'group'=>array('City.name')
                                    )
                                );//closing parentheses for find('list'...


    $this->render('/students/ajax_dropdown');
}


function add(){


    if (!empty($this->data)){
        /*var_dump($this->data);
        die(debug($this->Student->validationErrors)); */
        $student=$this->Student->saveAll($this->data,array('validate'=>'first'));
        if (!empty($student))
           {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your child\'s admission has been received. We will send you an email shortly.');
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home'));

            }


    } //for if (!empty....

     $states=$this->Student->State->find('list');

    $cities=array();
      $this->set(compact('states','cities'));

}//end function
```

}
?>

merry_parents_controller.php

```
<?php
 class MerryParentsController extends AppController{

var $name='MerryParents';


 }
 ?>
```

add.ctp

```
  <?php
 echo $javascript->link('prototype',false); 

echo $form->create('Student');
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Student Information</legend>';
echo $form->input('Student.name');

$options = array('Male'=>'Male','Female'=>'Female');
$attributes = array('value'=>'Male');
echo $form->radio('Student.gender',$options,$attributes);

echo $form->input('Student.dob', array('label'=>'Date of Birth',
                'dateFormat'=>'DMY', 
                'empty'=>true,
                'timeFormat' => '', 
            'minYear' => ( 
                    date('Y') - 5 
            ), 
            'maxYear' => ( 
                    date('Y') - 2 
            ) 
            ));
echo $form->input('Student.class_id', 
        array(
        'label'=>'Enquiry Class for',
        'empty'=>'Choose one',
'options'=>array('1'=>'Playgroup','2'=>'Nursery','3'=>'LKG', '4'=>'UKG')
        )
        );

echo '</fieldset>';

echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Parent Information</legend>';
//echo $form->input('Student.parent_id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $form->input('MerryParent.initial', 
array('empty'=>true,
'options'=>array('Dr'=>'Dr', 
                'Mr'=>'Mr', 
                'Mrs'=>'Mrs', 
                'Ms'=>'Ms')
)
);
echo $form->input('MerryParent.name', array('label'=>'Parent/Guardian Name'));
echo $form->input('MerryParent.email');
echo $form->input('MerryParent.landline');
echo $form->input('MerryParent.mobile');
echo $form->input('MerryParent.address');
      echo $form->input('Student.state_id');
 echo $form->input('Student.city_id');
      echo $form->input('MerryParent.postal_code');

      $options = array('url' => 'getcities', 'update' => 'StudentCityId');
  echo $ajax->observeField('StudentStateId', $options); //observes the drop down 
    changes in state id and makes an xmlHttpRequest when its contents have changed.


    echo '</fieldset>';

echo $form->end('Submit');
    ?>
```

ajax_dropdown.ctp

```
     <?php foreach($options AS $k=>$v) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put 0 in Model name and field, since you are saving just one student in a form. Try using Student.name instead of Student.0.name and so on for all fields. Also try to test with $validate => false if it saves then.

Comment: i tried what u said and i'm getting: warning 512:SQL Error: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`merry_flowers_db`.`students`, CONSTRAINT. This is because the parent.id is not getting inserted into student.parent_id (a foreign key). So, how do I ensure that parent_id gets inserted into the students table?

Comment: can you paste the dump of your data just before saveAll call?

Comment: array(2) { ["Student"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(13) "kenneth smith" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["dob"]=> array(3) { ["day"]=> string(2) "25" ["month"]=> string(2) "04" ["year"]=> string(4) "2008" } ["class_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["state_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["city_id"]=> string(1) "1" } ["MerryParent"]=> array(7) { ["initial"]=> string(2) "Mr" ["name"]=> string(10) "john smith" ["email"]=> string(15) "john7@yahoo.com" ["landline"]=> string(0) "" ["mobile"]=> string(12) "234238947239" ["address"]=> string(9) "heilbronn" ["postal_code"]=> string(6) "382947" } }

Comment: Hah, i found the prob after doing some revision in the cakephp Cookbook. The foreign key was named incorrectly in the students table, i changed parent_id to merry_parent_id coz the table name is merry_parents and now it works fine. Thanks a lot for your guidance. :)

Comment: Well its because you didn't follow the convention and cake couldn't able to get the right foreign key for student table. you have specified parent.id but cake will be looking for merry_parent_id. Check what should be the right syntax for foreign key according to conventions.

Comment: Yes, u are right. I was very careless. Now, i'm having problem populating the city select box based on what state the user selects. I'm using ajax for that. Do you know on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated my code to include the ajax code. So, do u know on where i'm making a mistake?

Comment: i copied prototype.js from cakephp/app/webroot/js into my application's /webroot/js folder and i'm not getting anymore errors. But still when i choose a state, city select box is not being populated. I have know idea on why it is still not working.

Comment: Hi, I noticed, that students_controller's getcities function is not at all rendering to ajax_dropdown.ctp. Coz' when i do a var_dump($options) in ajax_dropdown, nothing happens.

Please help, i've been trying to make this work for almost 2 weeks. :( 
thank you.

Comment: Finally, i solved the prob. Added function beforeFilter()//executed before any controller action logic
 { 
     if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() && $this->action = 'getcities'){
         $this->Security->enabled = false;
   } 
   
 } in StudentsController.

Comment: Finally I managed to solve the prob after 2 weeks of research and reading up. The problem was Cakephp's security component was blackholing Ajax's observeField request. So, the security component has to be disabled for the observeField to work. So, I added  beforeFilter code in my previous comment (found from the net) to StudentsController.